# How do I find the songs I tagged with a specific tag on Last.fm?

Tags: last.fm

How do I find the Last.fm songs that I tagged with a specific tag? I tried looking in my library, but there are too many. I tried looking at the songs with that tag, but there are too many. I only want the songs that I tagged.